# Scriptaculous Effect.Appear glitch onmouseover

Tags: css, scriptaculous

I've got a problem when using scriptaculous `Effect.Appear()` as a menu option, I wanted to create a flash-like menu but with pure css and scriptaculous.

I've got my desired outcome which is when I hover over a box, a text (with `display: none;`) appear above it and the box changes height and background color. Now the problem is that when my mouse move extremely fast and crazy over the box, the text remains (as if it was selected).

What I want is that as I hover the text appear, and if my mouse of out, the text disappear.

My codes

```
function ShowEffect(element){
   new Effect.Appear(element, 
   {duration:0.3, from:0, to:1.0, queue: 'front'});
}
function HideEffect(element){
   new Effect.Appear(element, 
   {duration:0.2, from:1.0, to:0, queue: 'end'});
}
```

The Divs

```
<div class="lefty" style="width: 90px; margin-right: 2px;">
                <div style="display: none;" id="clicker2text">ABOUT US</div>
                <div style="width: 90px;" onmouseover="ShowEffect('clicker2text')" onmouseout="HideEffect('clicker2text')"></div>
                </div>
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `onmouseover` attribute on the div use an event observer like this

```
$$('.lefty').invoke('observe','mouseover',ShowEffect);
$$('.lefty').invoke('observe','mouseout',HideEffect);
```

But I think this will work better as you are watching for the events that bubble up to body and then acting on it if is the right element.

```
$$('body').first().observe('mouseover',function(e){
    if(e.findElement().hasClass('lefty'))
    {
        ShowEffect(e.findElement());
    }
    else
    {
        //trigger for all of the menus just to make sure the are hidden
        //instead of stuck on
        $$('.lefty').each(function(element){
            if(element.visible())
            {
                HideEffect();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This should give you some ideas - see if it solves your problem.